# How to hide button after 5 clicks jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

In short I have multiple posts and each post have download button with unique data-click attribute,
**For example** `data-click="1"` for post 1 download button , `data-click="2"` for post 2 download button and so on. I want that if download button click 5 times for post 1 then after 5 clicks it hides , also it keeps hidden if refresh the page , I have written some code but it doesn't hide the button

```
               <script>//this script is responsible for adding a unique data-click= 0,1,2,3,4.....n to each resume post respectively.
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                      var PostId = 2;
                         var i = 1;  
                    $('.gotocls').each(function() {
                      jQuery(this).attr('data-click', i);
                      var ClickId = $(this).attr('data-click');
                      var LocalKey = PostId + '+' + ClickId;
                      if(localStorage.getItem(LocalKey)){
                        if(localStorage.getItem(LocalKey) == '5'){
                          $(this).hide();
                        //  alert('im m new here');
                        }
                      }
                      else{
                        localStorage.setItem(LocalKey,0);
                        alert('im game');
                      }
                       i++ 
                    });
                    });
            </script>
```

the above code add unique data click attribute to each downlaod button and check if localstorage value is 5

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
        
              $(document).ready(function(){
               $(".gotocls").click(function() {
                   var PostId = 2;
                  var ClickId = $(this).attr("data-click");
                 var LocalKey = PostId + '+' + ClickId;
                 count = localStorage.getItem(LocalKey);
                 count ++;
                   if(count > 5){
                        alert(count);
                            localStorage.setItem(LocalKey, 5);
                            $(this).hide();
                   }
                   else{
                    alert(count);
                        alert('imnot here');
                     localStorage.setItem(LocalKey, count);
                   }
               });
              });
    </script>
```

and my html code

```
<a  class="dkpdf-button gotocls" href="javascript:return false;">Download Now</a>
```

[image: view image]

[image: data-click1 for post 1 image]

Comment: Do you need to hide the button on the client-side?

Comment: @Dhrumilshah yes when the user clicks the button for 5 times it hides

Comment: can you please add HTML code also

Comment: Just a heads up, this would probably work fine unless it's important that you only can click 5 times. Having logic like this do allow for anyone to simply change that data-value (and/or local storage data) from the browsers developer tools.

Comment: I tried with your code also, it's working on my side, what exactly do you get the problem? even after refreshing the page, it keeps hiding

Answer (score 0):

For a better understanding, I set the simple code
**HTML**

```
<div>
    <button id="gotocls" class="gotocls">Download</button>
</div>
```

**Sctipt**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var LocalKey = "Click_Count"; // set key paramater
        count = localStorage.getItem(LocalKey); // get data from local storage
       
        if (count >= 5) //condition - if click count equal or greater than 5
        {

            $(".gotocls").hide(); // button hide

        }
    
        $(".gotocls").click(function () {
            //var PostId = 2;
            //var ClickId = $(this).attr("data-click");
           
            
            count++;
            if (count >= 5) {
                alert(count);
                localStorage.setItem(LocalKey, 5);
                $(this).hide();
            }
            else {
                alert(count);
                alert('imnot here');
                localStorage.setItem(LocalKey, count);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

you can change javascript as per your requirements, this will work on client-side

Comment: after adding this script all the downlaod buttons from all posts get hidden if we click on post 1 downlaod now button for 5 times

Comment: i didn't know you have multiple buttons, I tried with your code also, it's working on my side

Comment: on my side with my code.. 5 clicks wont work instead 1 click  working on clicking download now button for only 1 time it disaapears for that specific post only....can you please check  my second script...the error is somethere there